# Monitoring kubernetes pod health events

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus, grafana-loki

Currently I have setup kubernetes, with kube-state-metrics, prometheus and loki. For most things this work really well, but the one thing I am struggling with is finding the exact reason why containers might've restarted.

For running pods, it's quite easy to see, i.e. with `kubectl describe pod`, for example, I get the events below:

```
kubectl describe pod pod-name
.....
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From     Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----     -------
  Warning  Unhealthy  19m (x9 over 3h29m)  kubelet  message-here
```

This is very useful for troubleshooting exactly why a container have a lot of restarts, especially if using probes. But there are also other useful events.

However I cannot see any way to save these kind of events, in either loki or prometheus. But maybe I am missing something. I had expected `kube-state-metrics` to include such information but it seems not to be the case, I also do not see it anywhere in Loki.

Any tips on how I can save such events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst Prometheus and KSM are more focussed around metrics, eg: 'N number of pod restarts', Loki can be used for capturing events.

A good overview guide is [here](https://grafana.com/blog/2019/08/21/how-grafana-labs-effectively-pairs-loki-and-kubernetes-events/) which uses [eventrouter](https://github.com/heptiolabs/eventrouter) to push events into a backend (Loki or Elasticsearch for example)

Comment: Exactly something like that I've been looking for. Thank you!